# Umbraco multi-color menu tabs

Tags: asp.net, css, content-management-system, umbraco, menubar

I'm using the Asp.Net CMS Umbraco and would like some help to determine whether or not there is something specific about the Umbraco CMS that might make the task of creating a multi-colored menu bar... different from standard html and css manipulation.

The menu bar code that I'm using is based upon the friendly-ghost theme shipped with Umbraco.

Now the normal method for employing different colours in a menu would be something like

```
       div # menu ul.rMenu li.page-item-(some number) {background-color: # (whatever);}

        ...

        ...

<li class "rMenu-expand page-item-(the same number as above)"><a href="(link to whatever site on the menu)">
    <span> Wording for the particular tab </span></a></li>
```

And bingo... the (some-number) tab has the (whatever) colour!

---

However, Umbraco seems to be using a different set-up that is not entirely compatible with the above strategy. Should I be looking at *umbTextpage id   *parentID   *nodeType  ... or something entirely different that I haven't, as yet, noticed?

I believe that nodeName is being used for the wording of particular tabs... should I take it, then, that nodeType refers to the tabs themselves ???

---

That's great, thanks. However, the menu is generated dynamically using xslt. Do you think I should I attempt to insert that code (converted to xslt) into the menu generation process...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">

     <li>

       <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">

          <xsl:attribute name="class">current</xsl:attribute>

       </xsl:if>

      <a class="navigation" href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">

       <span><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></span>

      </a>

    </li>
```

... or attempt to use razor code after the fact (i.e. have the menu be created and subsequently cycle through the menu's elements, giving a numerical 'tag' to each node)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of Umbraco is that you have complete control of the layout. You can have it build your menu how ever you want.

I don't know whether you are using xslt or razor to generate your menu, but If you're looking trying to get a unique number to append to "page-number-" then use the node's Id, that won't change even if the name of the node is edited.

Using Umbraco 4.7 razor you do something like this:

```
@{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var node in Model.AncestorOrSelf().Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <li class="rMenu-expand page-item-@node.Id">
            <a href="@node.Url">
                <span>@node.Name</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow comments section is too difficult to use for this reply (such as the fact that StackOverflow automatically deletes reply formatting and new lines (and most whitespace) and places a 500 char limit on replies)

Comment: Yeah, the comment field isn't a great place for code samples, it's true. What you typically do is just edit your question, add your new stuff to it, then, in a comment, let us know you've made an update.

Comment: Whether you use the razor snippet or convert it to xslt, is entirely up to you. They both shoul work just as well. Just use whatever is most comfortable to you.

Comment: Oh, I just reread your question. The decision to use the razor snippet over xslt is an "either/or" you can't use both in this instance. Well, I guess technically you could :), but that would be complex and miserable.

Comment: Oh well, the xslt snippet above actually creates the menu in the first place. I'm just trying to work out if I can just add to the xslt's for each loop (obviously not with razor code!). This would seem the cleaner option (notwithstanding the conversion of razor to xslt) but it might be more complex (as it is imperative that the menu generation isn't messed up) than just having the razor's for each loop cycle through the menu after all the xslt has already compiled... o.O